# Lose 'text-selection' functionality after custom implementation for PSPDFKIT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I have a Reactjs project that implements PSPDFKIT as a pdfviewer. We are adding custom logic according to our needs. We need for annotations when the mouse pointer over them to open a popup/modal with some information/data we pass to it. This needs to happen smoothly when someone 'stop moving' its mouse on a highlight/annotation. So we add the logic as in the code I have below, but we have a problem. Although the process I mentioned before works fine, we lose some actions like the 'text selection' from PSPDFKIT when we need to make a text selection within an existing annotation (we have multiple annotations that are merged). I think our problem is the 'node' element we create to have the additional functionality - listeners as PSPDFKIT documentation refers. Any opinion on how to solve this? Or a better approach with the code provided? Thank you!

```
customRenderers: {
                Annotation: ({annotation}) =>{
                    if (
                    annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.TextAnnotation ||
                    annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.MarkupAnnotation ||
                    annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.LinkAnnotation ||
                    annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.HighlightAnnotation ||
                    annotation instanceof PSPDFKit.Annotations.UnderlineAnnotation
                    ) {
                    const node = instance.contentDocument.createElement("div");
                    node.classList.add('myAnnotationCustom')
                    node.dataset.annotationId = annotation.id;
                    node.style.cssText = "position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;pointer-events: all;";
                    node.innerHTML = `<div data-title="${annotation.id}"></div>`;


                    /**
                     * Function that triggered from mouse enter event
                     * @param {*} e
                     * @returns
                     */
                    const mouseoverListener = async function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();

                        // if match the conditional means that we have another opened annotation and return the value
                        // openedAnnotationId.current is null at first time and when we close the popup and clear the popUpState
                        if(openedAnnotationId.current !== null && openedAnnotationId.current !== annotation.id) return
                        if(isPopupOpened.current) return
                        if (annotation) {
                            mouseStopActionHasAnnotation.current = true;
                        }
                    };

                    /**
                     * Function that triggered from mouse leave event
                     * @param {*} e
                     */
                    const mouseLeaveListener = (e) => {
                        if(isPopupOpened.current) return
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        mouseStopActionHasAnnotation.current = false;
                    }

                    /**
                     * Function that triggered when mouse moving stops and you are inside an annotation node
                     */
                    const handleOpenPopup = () => {
                        setCurrentAnnotation(annotation);
                        openedAnnotationId.current = annotation.id;
                        isPopupOpened.current = true;
                        setShowPopup(true)
                    }

                    /**
                     * Function that triggered when mouse moving stops and you are out of annotation node
                     */
                    const handleCancelPopup = () => {
                        if(!isPopupOpened.current) {
                            setCurrentAnnotation(null);
                        }
                    }

                    /**
                     * Function that triggered with mousemove event and when stop moving mouse in triggers the logic inside setTimeout
                     * @param {*} event
                     */
                    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
                        if(isPopupOpened.current) return
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(() => {
                            if(annotation && mouseStopActionHasAnnotation.current) {
                                const mousePosition = {
                                    event: event,
                                    x: event.pageX - 80,
                                    y: event.pageY - 120
                                }
                                setMousePosition({
                                    top: mousePosition.y,
                                    left: mousePosition.x
                                })
                                handleOpenPopup()

                            } else {
                                handleCancelPopup();
                            }
                            node.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
                        }, 500);
                    }

                    node.addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseoverListener, {once: true});
                    node.addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseLeaveListener, {once: true});
                    node.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

                    return {
                        node,
                        append: true,
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Anyone can help with this ?